# Can I add player rotation to this command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to implement player rotation in order to work with the teleport argument, as such:

`/tp [target player] <x> <y> <z> [<y-rot> <x-rot>]`

But in this command instead:

`/execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~ if entity @e[distance=..5] run tp @p ~12 ~15 ~`

Is it possible?

Comment: If it works with the regular `/tp` command, then why wouldn't it work with that command? The best thing you can do is to just try it out. I think the command likely won't do what you expect, but it should work.

Comment: @bearb001 It somehow doesn't work when I add the "[<y-rot> <x-rot>]" argument. The relative coordinates after the /tp command go red. Maybe I'm typing the degrees in the wrong place?

Comment: It works for me, what command do you use exactly when you add the rotation? Does it work without the `execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~ if entity @e[distance=..5] run` part?

Comment: @bearb001 I'll try that out, one second.

Comment: @bearb001 Strange, works perfectly now even with the `execute positioned ~ ~-1 ~ if entity @e[distance=..5] run` part. It might've been a typo I made or something. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Out if curiosity, what do you want to use this command for? It looks a bit unusual.

Comment: @bearb001 I'm making a fake Nether portal, that tp's you to a upper floor of a tower. But I'm using the command on 4 different portals with 4 different orientations, so I want to implement the rot argument to make the player always face the floor's balcony, if that makes any sense hahahah

Comment: Right now what the command does is teleport the nearest player if there is any entity nearby, so if a zombie is close to the command block, then the nearest player gets teleported, regardless of where that player is, even if it's hundreds of blocks away.

Comment: @bearb001 Damn. Tried it just now, and indeed the zombie I spawned tp'd me to that floor. I've tried using @p instead of @e in the past (I assume that's the problem, I'm honestly a complete noob to minecraft) but it doesn't work for some reason. Edit: I did set the "mobSpawn" gamerule to false, just so mobs wouldn't grief the world. But it's only a temporary solution I guess.

Comment: And what is the `positioned` part supposed to do? It shouldn't really change much. Try to use `/tp @a[distance=..5] ~12 ~14 ~ <rotation>` instead.

Comment: @bearb001 Wow, `/tp @p[distance=..5] ~12 ~14 ~ 0 0` works perfectly fine. I got the suggestion to use the /execute positioned command on another thread I made a while ago, but I guess this works too! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: `@p` teleports the nearest player while `@a` teleports all players, so using `@a` would probably be a little better if many players try to enter at once. For example, if 20 players try to enter at exactly the same time, then they would get teleported one after the other, the last one would have to wait 1 second, because all the other players get teleported first. `@a` would teleport all 20 at the same time. You can use `@p`, but `@a` is probably a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete of `/execute` is a bit messed up. For example it only shows `as` when you enter `/execute rotated` . But you can still do this:

```
/execute rotated 12.3 ~-45.6 run <command>
```

This is also documented [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/execute&oldid=1412142)).